# Layout of Power lines to extension board (Temperature Sensor)

Tags: power, pcb, sensor, layout

I'm designing an (single sided) extension board that will hold a 3-pin temperature sensor ([TSIC 506](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57427.pdf)). As the order of the pins go from 1 Vcc, 2 Signal, 3 GND I wonder if I should follow the same order in the cable connecting the board to an MCU? Or would it be better to have 1 Vcc, 2 GND, 3 Signal on the cable?

As a more general question, should ground and power lines in a cable also carrying signals be next to each other, or as far as possible from each other?

I attach two layouts of the board I did.

First, power lines apart:

[image: PCB layout with power lines apart]

---

Second one, with power and ground next to each other:

[image: PCB layout with power lines next to each other]

Comment: Is this just a one or two layer board?

Comment: Planned for single layer.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a question of „who should be next to who“.

If you want a design that is robust concerning EMI (I assume that‘s what you‘re after), then you have to defeat 3 enemies:

1) inductive coupling (loop to loop). Current only flow in loops and loops carrying current affect each other. So you must figure out all loops and find a way not to interfere. Usually this is done by minimizing loop area.

2) capacitive coupling. A plate of a plate capacitor influences the other plate through cap. coupling. Making use of this is called “shielding”. You can shield signals with e.g. a GND plane so they won’t be affected by cap. coupling.

3) galvanic coupling. The simplest form of interference happens when multiple currents (signals) share a line. The receiver of one signal will also see the other signals. This can be addressed with seperate lines for each signal or a star grounding concept.

In your design, you could make GND as a plane (2 sided board) and you could use a shielded cable where you connect GND. You could also make the area (loop) between +5V and SIGNAL as small as possible.

Comment: Solid terms of EMI don't exist. I further wonder if you need to fight galvanic coupling. Galvanic coupling is not the opposite of galvanic isolation.

Comment: I need to read up on how to properly identify loop areas. As for the +5V and SIGNAL I would also have to account for the mcu side, right?

Comment: Yes, just minimize the loops as best as you can on each side. Identify each loop and consider what happens to the signal if there is a EMI induced current flowing in that loop.

Answer (score -1):

If this is just a one or two layer PWB, then it really doesn't matter which approach you take.

Any interference/EMI is going to come in broadside to the board (probably), and the power and return (ground) traces are not going to do anything to protect the signal trace, so matter how they are placed relative to the signal trace.